# Inline style does not want to change when clicked on div

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to toggle the nav when a div is clicked (the menu). The console does log that the showNav changes, but it does not work. It only works when I change the style manually inside the div.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { VegetarianContext } from '../contexts/VegetarianContext'

const Navbar = () => {
const { toggleVegetarian } = useContext(VegetarianContext);
let showNav = true;
return (
    <div className="navbar" style={{visibility: showNav ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}>
        <nav>
            <div className="close" onClick={() => {
                showNav = !showNav;
                console.log(showNav);
            }}>
                <img className="close" src={require("../img/tacomenu.png")} />
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li className="vegetarian"><a onClick={toggleVegetarian}>Are you vegetarian?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
);
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Look at [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-render some components, you should use `state`.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { VegetarianContext } from '../contexts/VegetarianContext'

const Navbar = () => {
  const { toggleVegetarian } = useContext(VegetarianContext);
  //let showNav = true;
  const [showNav, setShowNav] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="navbar" style={{visibility: showNav ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}>
        <nav>
            <div className="close" onClick={() => {
                //setShowNav(!showNav) // it works as Toggle
                setShowNav(false) // it works as Close only
            }}>
                <img className="close" src={require("../img/tacomenu.png")} />
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Order</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li className="vegetarian"><a onClick={toggleVegetarian}>Are you vegetarian?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```